# Is a wrapper class for an already existing registry class a good approach?

Tags: c++, qt, oop

In Qt, there is obviously a class to read and write to registry the `QSettings` (and I am only talking in Windows perspective). The normal instinct is to use that class whenever we need to read/write values to the registry but is it really 'object oriented'?

I feel like (and what I have done) is write my own registry class for my application which uses 'QSettings' internally. I forbid my application to use `QSettings` directly and require that all registry should be handled through my own class with I have named 'Registry`.

Consider the following example from my old code:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSettings_triggered()
{
    SettingsDialog * settings = new SettingsDialog;

    settings->exec();

    if ( settings->result() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        IP = QSettings().value( IP_ADDRESS, DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS).toString();
        emit ui->actionRefresh_Devices->triggered();
    }

     delete settings;
}
```

In in my new code this function changes slighly:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSettings_triggered()
{
    SettingsDialog * settings = new SettingsDialog;

    settings->exec();

    if ( settings->result() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        IP = Registry().getLastIP();
        emit ui->actionRefresh_Devices->triggered();
    }

     delete settings;
}
```

Even though its very slight change but it feels a lot more object oriented to me. Would you agree?

Along the same line I have separate functions for each quantity even though they all are strings. Would you agree this is good practice or it just adding extra code? Here is my small `Registry` class.

```
class Registry
{
public:
    Registry();
    ~Registry();

protected:
    QSettings settings;

public:
    QString getSyncPath();
    void setSyncPath(QString syncPath);

    QString getLastIP();
    void setLastIP(QString ip);

    void writeCustomIPs(const QStringList& customIPs );
    QStringList readCustomIPs();

};
```

To summarize, object oriented is about using classes and we do have a class for registry so check mark for that but it's still just too generic. Does wrapping such generic classes in another more specific class by composition a good practice in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for what you've done is a facade.  You've put a layer of abstraction between your event method and the interaction with the registry.

One of the biggest benefits of using a facade is that you can change the underlying implementation of how your program interacts with the registry by only making changes to the facade - i.e. if in the future you decide to use a different way of reading the registry instead of QSettings, then your event method that calls `Registry().getLastIP()` doesn't have to change, just the implementation within the `getLastIP` method has to change, and that's a good thing.

Adding extra layers of abstraction for no reason isn't a good idea - it makes code harder to maintain (harder to understand and harder to debug).  So always evaluate whether you're adding unnecessary complexity.  But in general, what you've done is not a bad design.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thought this way but since you pointed out, yes it being facade make sense. I feel like my code is more readable too this way by calls like `Registry().getLastIP()` which speaks for itself than using QSettings there.